# SNMP Forward to DD WRT For Logging?

Tags: monitoring, snmp, bandwidth, firmware

I multiple routers across different locations that use a proprietary GRE VPN connection.
What I would like to do is use the SNMP ability of these proprietary routers in conjunction with a DD WRT on each network.

I would like to use the DD WRT for bandwidth monitoring on the proprietary router's SNMP port setup.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey, 
I am not sure if I completely understand your question.

SNMP has two basic operation modes:

- pull from a management station (directly or via proxy), this is used to e.g. obtain metrics from your routers (amount of data transferred etc.)
- push (aka Trap) to actively inform the management station of error conditions.

In the subject you say "forward" which sounds to me like traps, which are usually not used to transfer monitoring data to a management station (or your DD WRT).
Or in other words the DD WRT would need to actively pull (snmpget) the values from the other routers and do something with them.
What may be possible is to set up thresholds on those routers (e.g. on bandwidth usage) and then have them send traps to the DD WRT in this case.

Comment: Thats a good idea. I found a solution using a software package called cacti.

Comment: When you consider this answer as good idea, would you please vote for it or even accept it as best answer?